# NextJs internationalization with i18next how to handle API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next

I have installed the language pack and I am using it for different languages. No problem here.
My problem is,
Let's say the user chose the Italian language option. Then, he sent a request to the service and the response is in English. How can I check this? Where and how will I check the response returned from the service? What is the solution for this? For example, when the user wants to create, the service response is successfully created. But this answer has to be in Italian.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own, translated messages that you display instead of what's returned by the API? That way you have control over what gets shown to the user. API messages are usually not very user-friendly anyway.

Comment: I found a answer.  When i request ı am sending request headers accept-language and ı check the backend accepted language. then ı return response